# Redirection is not working after selecting options

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, magento

We are Displaying Drop-down options for brands & models [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases/)

[image: demonstration]

After selecting dropdown options & if we click on "**See Cases**", we want to redirect to particular URL with selected options as name.

We are doing some AJAX code. When we click on button, its displaying proper **models and brands ids** but its not redirecting to proper URL.

We want something like [here](http://www.dailyobjects.com/select-mobile-tablet-case-model)

**PHP**

```
<a href="#" onclick="geturlandredirec()"><span class ="cc5"> See Cases > </span> </a>
```

**script**

```
<script>
 function geturlandredirec()
{

 var brand=$('brand_select').value;
 var model=$('model_select').value;
 array = [brand, model];

  alert(array)

   url="<?php echo Mage::getbaseUrl()?>customized-mobile-cases/customcase/ajax";

   new Ajax.Request(url, {
       method: 'POST',

         onFailure: function(response){
   },
parameters: {
    brand: brand, model: model
  },
 onSuccess: function(response)
 {
            window.location = response.responseText
   return ;
 }
     });
}

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to redirect on a successful response from the server, yet the URL is returning 404 Not Found.

Comment: The proper way would be correct the URL you are trying to send the information to.  
Currently it is http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases/customcase/ajax  
What URL is it supposed to be?

Comment: we want to redirect to this url : [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases/customcase/)

Comment: I'm still having trouble trying to figure out, how your application is supposed to work. As I've said previously, you are currently sending an AJAX request to nonexistent page and expecting it to return an URL to which you should redirect. What is supposed to be the URL of the script to which you are sending an AJAX request?

Comment: i want to redriect to this [page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases/customcase/) is i am doing anything wrong in code ?

Comment: You are redirecting only on successful AJAX request. That is correct, as you are expecting the URL to which redirect to as a response. Yet, the response is currently HTTP 404 Not Found. The script you are asking for the adress doesn't exist.